# Getting count of results in file, by first 3 characters.

Tags: batch-file

I have a file that has several lines, some with matching customer codes. Lets say we have customers ABC, DEF, and GHI. Each customer has serveral matching lines so the file would be like:

```
ABC1
ABC2
DEF1
DEF2
DEF3
GHI1
GHI2
GHI3
GHI4
```

I want a batch script that will run and return a count of each file by customer. So the output for the above file would be

```
ABC = 2 files
DEF = 3 files
GHI = 4 files
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: are all the customers three letters strings?

Comment: All the customers do have a 3 letter string identifier. There are however many more customers than in the example and new ones can be added somewhat frequently. So I suppose it needs to check for unique first three characters and then count.

Comment: I am presuming you are on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in (file.txt) do (
   set line=%%a
   set /A lines[!line:~0,3!]+=1
)

for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set lines[') do echo %%a = %%b files
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash with grep can do this easily. Something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ABC=$(grep -c "ABC" FILE)
DEF=$(grep -c "DEF" FILE)

echo "ABC = "$ABC" files"
```

Comment: How the rest of customers are specified? Is it necessary to insert two lines (`XYZ=$(...)` and `echo "XYZ = "$XYZ files"`) for _each_ customer?

Comment: Here the comments are in double quotes. We use two sets of quotes because we do not want to put a variable inside quotes.

Comment: (?) Is it necessary to insert two lines for each one of the customers?

Comment: It will still print as one line. This script is an example:
line1: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
line2: `variable=7848484848`
line3: `echo "here is a test "$variable" and this is the 2nd quote"`
printed to terminal: `here is a test 7848484848 and this is the 2nd quote`

Comment: Excuse me. I don't know Bash/grep, but I assume that your Bash script just calculate the number of files from `ABC` and `DEF` customers, and that it show the result of `ABC` customer only, so it needs an additional line to show `DEF` result, and two additional lines for `GHI` customer, and two more lines for _each_ additional customer. If this is true, then this solution does not solve the problem, because "There are however many more customers than in the example and new ones can be added somewhat frequently". I think this is the answer to my questions...

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the request. I'll need to think if there is a bash solution to this, but your solution above is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set cust_file=.\cusomers.txt

for /f "useback" %%# in ("%cust_file%") do (
    set "line=%%~#"
    set cust_id=!line:~0,3!
    if not defined cust_c_!cust_id! (
        set /a cust_c_!cust_id!=1
    ) else (
        set /a cust_c_!cust_id!=cust_c_!cust_id!+1
    )
)

rem set cust_c_

for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=_=" %%c in ('set cust_c_') do (
    echo %%c = %%d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are on Windows, but just in case you also have a proper OS available ;-)

```
cut -c1-3 YourFile | sort |uniq | while read cust; do n=$(grep -c $cust file);echo $cust:$n; done
```

That says... extract first 3 characters of every line, sort them and remove duplicates (with `uniq`). Read these customer ids one at a time in a loop, and ask `grep` to count the number of occurences of each in the file.

Or, if you have `awk`

```
awk '{id=substr($0,1,3);counts[id]++} END{for(x in counts)print x,counts[x]}' YourFile
```

That says... take the first 3 letters of each line and save in variable `id`. Increment the `counts[]` array, element `id`. At the end of the input file, whizz through the `counts[]` array and, for each element, print its index and how many times it was seen.